# HTTP call with Socks proxy

Tags: sockets, proxy, socks

I want to use socks proxy to reach to a server. But something is not right. I have a proxy and the owner of the proxy claims it to be a socks proxy.

I simplified my problem and now trying to reach to google.com using the below code.

```
 URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");  
 URLConnection connection = null;  
 SocketAddress proxySocketAddress1 =  new InetSocketAddress("XXXXXXXXXX", 8081);  
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxySocketAddress1);  
 connection = url.openConnection(proxy);  
 connection.setConnectTimeout(150000);  
 connection.connect();
```

Connection cannot be established with google. But if I use PROXY type as HTTP then it is working i.e. if I replace line 4 of the above code with

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxySocketAddress1);
```

I tried to reach google.com using browser (chrome) and specifying the same proxy as "socks proxy" and "http proxy" and were able to open google afterwards.

Not sure when the given proxy is working as SOCKS proxy in browser then why it is not working in the code?

If I get this working then ultimately I want to do something like:

```
SocketAddress socketAddress =  new InetSocketAddress(proxyHostname,proxyPort);  
Proxy socketProxy =  new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socketAddress);  
socket = new Socket(socketProxy);  

InetSocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostIP,hostPort);    
socket.connect(socketAddress,100000);
```

Any suggestion i could try?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this proxy is not a socks proxy but an HTTP proxy, because

- it works if you use it as a http proxy, it does not work as a socks proxy
- if you specify it in google as http AND socks proxy it will probably just use the socks proxy setting for other protocols (https, ftp..) and use the http proxy setting for http - so it works there too as http proxy
- 80xx are typical ports for http proxies (e.g. 8000,8001,8080,8081) because 80 is the "normal" port for http, socks proxies instead use usually something like 1080

Comment: Actually it is a SOCKS4 proxy. When I tried to connect thru as SOCKS4 then I am able to reach google thru code.

Comment: Then it is strange that the java application can use it as an HTTP proxy but not as an SOCKS proxy. Maybe you should do a tcpdump to see whats really going on.